# Show that if [b] and [c] are both multiplicative inverses of [a] in Z_n then b = c(mod n).

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I am having some trouble getting started with this problem. I know that I am going to need the following proposition in the proof:
Let n > 0 be an integer. Then the following conditions hold for all integers a, b, c, d:
a) If a = c(mod n) and b = d(mod n), then a +/- b = c +/- d (mod n), and ab = cd(mod n).
b) If a + c = a + d(mod n), then c = d(mod n). If ac = ad(mod n) and (a,n) = 1, then c = d(mod n).

Any help or suggestions is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have $ab - 1 = kn, ac - 1 = pn\Rightarrow ab - ac = (k-p)n\Rightarrow n\mid a(b-c)$, but $(a,n) = 1 \Rightarrow n \mid (b-c)$

Comment: And the reason that (a,n) (that is gcd(a,n)) equals 1 is that if d|a and d|n then  d|ac and d|pn so d|(ac-pn)=1.